# Taylor series of $1\over z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How to find the Taylor series of $1\over z^2$ near $2$
( in the power of $z-2$) 
I have tried to write it in the form:
          $1\over ((z-2)^2+4z-4)$
   But I reached nothing, any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series about 2 : $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!} (z-2)^n$.
Now $f(z) = z^{-2}$ is analytic about 2.
$f'(z) = (-2)z^{-3}$ and in general $f^{(n)}(z) = (-1)^{n}(n+1)!z^{-(n+2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$. $f$ is analytic at $2$, so its Taylor series expansion converges to it. Then:

$$f(x) = f(2) + \frac{f'(2)}{1!}(x - 2) + \frac{f''(2)}{2!}(x-2)^2 + \ldots + \frac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}(x-2)^n + \ldots= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(2)}{k!}(x-2)^k$$

Try to find a formula for $f^{(k)}(x)$

$$f'(x) = \frac{-2}{x^3}, f''(x) = \frac{6}{x^4},\ldots, f^{(k)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^k(k+1)!}{x^{k+2}}$$

Then, $$f^{(k)}(2) = \frac{(-1)^k(k+1)!}{2^{k+2}}$$

Comment: Why (k-1)! Not (k+1)!   ???

Comment: Ghalat matba3i. Halla2 saret mazbouta.

Comment: 7ada lebnene !!

Comment: Btw thank for help,

Comment: You're welcome.